# Jupyter Notebook does not take PIL.Image objects as return from util/functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, python-imaging-library, jupyter

I am currently facing an Issue with returning PIL.Image objects to a JupyterNotebook, I abstracted several functions into a `util\` directory.
The functions are imported correctly and can be executed from the Notebook but the return Value is always `None`. Returning other Values to the Notebook works fine.

I am running Python 3.10.7 in a local pyenv, `.venv/` is properly set up and everything is running in the same env.

This function is supposed to get a path to an Image and return a downscaled version:

```py
from PIL import Image
from util.functionPerformance import functionPerformance 

class DownScaler:

    @staticmethod
    @functionPerformance
    def scale(img_path:Image ,x_factor:float, y_factor:float, verbose:bool=False) -> Image:
        picture = Image.open(img_path)
        picture.resize((int(picture.width*x_factor),int(picture.height*y_factor)))
        
        # This Line is here to show that, the object exist        
        
        print(picture)                       
        return picture
```

But if I call it from the Notebook like this:

```py
     scaled_img = DownScaler.scale(image_path, .2, .2)
     print(scaled_img)
```

The resulting output is:

```
<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=300x400 at 0x17EF2F4F0>
None
```

The function can print out the object, why is it not returned?

I tried to move the File out of the `util\`directory, and I did try if there is an Issue with returning to the Notebook in general.

The function:

```py
def test_return(value:any):
    return value
```

returns values as expected, when I call it from the Notebook:

```py
value = {" I tried":[str, int, ..., PIL.Image]}
test_return(value)
```

even with PIL.Image objects.

What would be grateful for any help I could get, and please be nice.

Comment: The easy answer to why your function's return value is vanishing is that the `@functionPerformance` decorator you're applying to it is broken, and failing to pass on the value.

Comment: I have to correct myself, I tired it again without it and now it works.
Thanks Mate